# How to check if an input is the same as a string

Tags: python

```
#Confirm to play

Answer = input("Ready to play [y/n]?")

class confirmation(object):
    def menu(self,Answer):
        confirmation.Answer = Answer 
        if Answer == "y":
            print("Let's play!")
```

I want to know what's wrong with the code. It does not raise any error but i think something is wrong with the function, since it does not print "Let's play!". I also tried to put an else statement at the end as to print an error in case the problem was due to "Answer" not being equal to "y" but nothing was printed neither. So my guess is the function is just being ignored? if is that so, why?

Comment: please provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code

Comment: Have you called the function menu

Comment: Also you never call the function that I can see

Comment: i can put the whole code since is not that big... would it help?

Comment: can you give me an example on how i'd do it?

Comment: Here is an example   
def my_function():
  print("Hello from a function")

my_function() 
So in your case you would do menu() to call the function with any personifies that you specify

Comment: Sorry guys it seems like i cant edit my question, i was trying to put the rest of the code, but i think is not related to the problem

Comment: thx ShadowGunn i'll try

Comment: Did you see the response that should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Answer = input("Ready to play [y/n]?")

class Confirmation():
    def menu(self): 
        if Answer == "y":
            print("Let's play!")

c = Confirmation()
c.menu()
```

The `object` and `Answer` arguments are not necessary. I also changed the class to `Confirmation`, instantiated it, and called the `menu()` method.